# Move viewpager and recycler together

Tags: android

I have a fragment which consists of a image flipper in the viewpager and a recycler view
This is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/slider_pager">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_hotels"
        android:background="@color/back1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slider_pager">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What can i do so that the viewpager scrolls up together with the recycler view and hide below action bar. Recycler view has its own scroll view so i cannot put this relative layout under a scrollview as recycler view scroll clashes with it.
How can i make them move together?

Comment: Why don't you implement your view pager as one of recylerview views?

Comment: i cant do that because recycler view has a complicated access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the ViewPager as a header to the RecyclerView. Although there are many ways to code this manually, I would take a look at the [HeaderRecyclerView project on Github](https://github.com/Karumi/HeaderRecyclerView) as it makes this process a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put ViewPager inside android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar Layout in xml.
And use android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout as Parent Layout  to achieve this.